Datalist not working on Apple Mac Safari 18.1
I simplified the code from https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/jOVqGaJ to the following.
<input list="countrydata1" id="country1" name="country1" size="50" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="countrydata1">
  <option>Afghanistan</option>
  <option>Åland Islands</option>
</datalist>

Safari is not displaying the datalist.
Works great on Chrome
